# Rudimentary Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I get the following error with the Hello world syntax in the Google Chrome Development Console.

**JavaScript**

```
console.log("Hello World');
```

**Error Message**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Could you tell me the cause?

Comment: Thank you for the revision.
I am a newbie and asked a question to experience stackoverflow.

It seems that the questions were closed due to various low levels, but I'm sorry that I didn't have any bad intentions to disturb the place.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have open your text with double quotes and close with single qoation mark…

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

works fine

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code worked fine.
I am a newbie and asked a question to experience stackoverflow.

It seems that the questions were closed due to various low levels, but I'm sorry that I didn't have any bad intentions to disturb the place.

Thank you for your cooperation.